# android drawable how to create this

Tags: android, android-layout

hi am trying to create this layout , am hoping to use view with it src pointing to drawaable with a shape and tip

[image: title here]
[image: title here](https://res.cloudinary.com/hashnode/image/upload/v1477050769/ismtsuj44lbvsksjztjh.png)[![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n90zl.png)
place that in the recyclerview ontop of the image view

```
<RelativeLayout
        ....
          >
     <View 
        align_parentTop= true
        src= " drawable with an invert tip inside "
        ....
          />
     <ImageView //actual image here 
         ... />
```

but i can create the shape i and also to convert it to xml , so it supports all sizes

Comment: You should draw the shape using primitives in Java.  That way it's 100% supported everywhere.  You really don't need the XML at all.

Comment: Use a 9patch PNG file

Comment: @durbnpoisn how to go about it can u suggest any resources

Comment: Just do a Google search for "drawing primitives android".  That'll tell you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create rotated image with `android:scaleY="-1"` attribute and draw the Tip on `Canvas` by `drawPath`, like below. 
Only change `scaleType` for images and triangle angles as you need.

**layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgInvertTip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:scaleY="-1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgInvertTip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView imgInvertedTip = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgInvertTip);
        ImageView imgPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPhoto);

        Drawable photo = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.photo);
        imgInvertedTip.setBackground(photo);
        imgPhoto.setImageDrawable(photo);

        ViewTreeObserver vto = imgInvertedTip.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                imgInvertedTip.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

                int width = imgInvertedTip.getMeasuredWidth();
                int height = imgInvertedTip.getMeasuredHeight();
                Bitmap tip = createTip(width, height);

                imgInvertedTip.setImageBitmap(tip);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private Bitmap createTip(int width, int height) {
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        int tipStep = height / 2;

        Point a = new Point(tipStep, 0);
        Point b = new Point(tipStep * 2, 90);
        Point c = new Point(tipStep * 3, 0);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_EVEN_ODD);
        path.lineTo(a.x, a.y);
        path.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
        path.lineTo(c.x, c.y);
        path.close();

        Bitmap tip = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tip);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        return tip;
    }
```

Comment: this is supposed to happen in a recycler this much computation is not not that good  , dont you think, i realise the easiest way would be use another image before the actual image , problem i can use vector so scaling is issue with phone of different screen size

Comment: is there a way to extend your above code without passing actual photo ,(ie not the actually maybe a resource )`imgInvertedTip.setBackground(photo);`
as am using glide to render the image from url, thanks for your respsone

Comment: Ok. Please, update your question (about vector using), it will be perfect